# PySpark to_utc_timestamp return the same time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, timestamp, timezone

I have a table which has a datetime in string type. I want to convert it into UTC timestamp. My local time zone is CDT. I first convert datetime into timestamp.

```
table = table.withColumn('datetime_dt', unix_timestamp(col('datetime'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))
```

Then, I try to convert this timestamp column into UTC time.

```
table = table.withColumn('datetime_UTC',  to_utc_timestamp(table.datetime_dt, 'CDT'))
```

I also try this

```
table = table.withColumn('datetime_UTC',  to_utc_timestamp(col('datetime_dt'), 'CDT'))
```

But it returns the same results. Here are some examples.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   datetime         |     datetime_dt     |    datetime_UTC     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2019-01-01 00:49:00 | 2019-01-01 00:49:00 | 2019-01-01 00:49:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2019-01-01 02:06:00 | 2019-01-01 02:06:00 | 2019-01-01 02:06:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2019-01-02 05:15:00 | 2019-01-02 05:15:00 | 2019-01-02 05:15:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does it give the same time without any conversion? I import `to_utc_timestamp` from `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify timezone as **`CST`**(or) **`America/Chicago`** instead of **`CDT`**, We don't have to explicitly mention about daylight saving time.

- Spark internally calculates and adds **`+5:00/+6:00`** based on the date.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|                 dt|
#+-------------------+
#|2019-01-01 00:49:00|
#|2019-11-01 00:49:00|
#+-------------------+

df.withColumn('datetime_UTC',  to_utc_timestamp(col('dt'), 'CST')).show(10,False)

#or

df.withColumn('datetime_UTC',  to_utc_timestamp(col('dt'), 'America/Chicago')).show(10,False)

#+-------------------+---------------------+
#|dt                 |datetime_UTC         |
#+-------------------+---------------------+
#|2019-01-01 00:49:00|2019-01-01 06:49:00.0|
#|2019-11-01 00:49:00|2019-11-01 05:49:00.0|
#+-------------------+---------------------+
```